# Make a list of iterative objects from 3 arrays in js

Tags: javascript

I have 3 arrays:

```
keys = ['first','second']
ycor = [200,400]
xcor = [[375,75],[75]]
```

I am thinking of how to get them to:

```
[
  {
    'first': 200,
    'second': [375,75]
  },
  {
    'first': 400,
    'second': [75]
  }
]
```

The primary attempt was to use the forEach() function, but only managed to reach a 2 sided case and unidentifiable by node.

```
var result = []
keys.forEach((i,v,w) => result[i] = (xcor[v],ycor[w]))
```

Is it possible at all?

Comment: just made an update, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the values arrays and map new objects.

This approach uses [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for taking the old object at the same index `j` of the result array.

```js
var keys = ['first', 'second'],
    ycor = [200, 400],
    xcor = [[375, 75], [75]],
    result = [ycor, xcor].reduce(
        (r, a, i) => a.map((v, j) => ({ ...r[j], [keys[i]]: v })),
        []
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```